# How to handle data from two forms in one view?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

So I have two `forms.ModelForm` for my two models

First:

```
class TranslatorChoice(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id',None)
        super(TranslatorChoice, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['owner'].queryset = Translator.objects.all().filter(owner_id = self.user_id)
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset =  None)
    class Meta:
        model = Translator
        fields = ('owner',)
```

Second:

```
class ProfileChoice(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id',None)
    super(ProfileChoice, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['login'].queryset = Profile.objects.all().filter(created_by_id = self.user_id)

login = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= None, label='Profile')
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('login',)
```

I've tried writing a `view` for them but it doesn't work, seems like it just won't save because whenever I hit submit button it just refreshes the page and cleans the fields without redirecting me to needed URL. The model instances in my DB aren't updated either.

Here's the view:

```
def link_profile(request):
context = {
'form': ProfileChoice(user_id=request.user.id),
'form2': TranslatorChoice(user_id=request.user.id)
}
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileChoice(request.POST)
    form2 = TranslatorChoice(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        login = form.cleaned_data.get('login')
        translator = form.cleaned_data.get('owner')
        link = Profile.objects.get(login=login)
        link.owner = login
        link.save(['owner'])
        form.save()
        form2.save()
        return redirect('dashboard')
return render(request, 'registration/link.html', context)
```

I know also something is wrong is because I am using to many `save` functions. I just don't have any experience in creating `views` like that...

Sharing my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Add profile</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>

    {{ form.as_table }} {{ form2.as_table }}
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Link</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}`
```

And my `urls.py` part with the view:

```
url(r'^link/', views.link_profile),
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your urls.py or the form in your template so it's not clear if the view is being executed, or how you're passing your forms. But, here's something that might work if you're not doing it already.

{{ form.as_table }}
    {{ form2.as_table }}

FYI: there are some indentation issues with your code but I'm assuming that that's just something that happened when you pasted it here.

Comment: Tried this and nothing really changed. Added url and my template to the question though.

Comment: Your form is missing an action. Look for "action" on this page to see an example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/