# Form is always not valid/Cannot assign instance

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I've been struggling with my issue for a while. It continues my previous question: [How to handle data from two forms in one view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453476/how-to-handle-data-from-two-forms-in-one-view)

I figured out that the problem is in this form:

```
class TranslatorChoice(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id',None)
        super(TranslatorChoice, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['owner'].queryset = Translator.objects.all().filter(owner = self.user_id)
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset =  None)
    class Meta:
        model = Translator
        fields = ('owner', )
```

Its' model:

```
class Translator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='created_translators'
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

And the view:

```
def link_translator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TranslatorChoice(request.POST)
        if  form.is_valid():
            pass
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = TranslatorChoice(user_id=request.user)
```

With the code above the form gives me options to choose from but whenever I hit submit the form asks me to select a valid choice. However, if I change `Translator.objects.all().filter(owner = self.user_id)` to `Translator.objects.all()` `form.is_valid()` gives me true but another error appears:

```
ValueError at /linkt/
Cannot assign "<Translator: rawkymonk>": "Translator.owner" must be a "User" instance.
```

My guess that the main problem is `ModelChoiceField` so if there's an alternative to it please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

`owner` is a foreign key to `User` hence I think the queryset should use that model. Try

```
self.fields['owner'].queryset = User.objects.filter(id=self.user_id)
```

I didn't test the above code.

Comment: I tested this. It's the same, whenever I submit form it says invalid choice.